# Generate Negative IDs on objects and preventing the Integer overflow

Tags: .net, vb.net, integer, overflow

I have an object, say Dog. For each Dog the DB generates an unique identificator - ID.

But before saving the Dog in the DB I should generate a temporary (negative ID).

So, I created a shared (static) _lastId = 0 in the Class Dog.

In the Dog's constructor I just decrement the lastId.

But once I save the dog in the DB or the Dog "dies" in the Garbage collector, the negative ID is not used anymore for that object, so could be used by other Dogs, that are alive but not saved.

because max Integer = `2,147,483,647`, if I do a lot of generation-supressions of large lists of Dog's I could exceed the maximum limit of the integer...

```
Private Shared _LastId = 0

Public Sub New()
  Me.Id = _LastId - 1
```

What "recycling" mecanism could be used here to prevent the overflow?

Comment: Why do you need to track _lastId at all?  Are you using that to determine the ID of the most recently inserted row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options

1

Use a separate TempID that is Int64.

Override Equals and == to be smart enough to use the either TempID or ID.

But don't change the Hash when the object gets a real ID.

2

Or use Int64 for the ID (temp and real).
On the positive side you happen to only use Int32.

3

Implement Dispose on the Dog and give back the -ID there.

And give back the -ID when the Dog gets a positive ID.

Have HashSet of recycled -ID and take from that list before getting a new -ID.

Comment: +1 for 3rd option. "Int64" does not fit the initial conditions of "Integer" for the ID...

Comment: Why are you restricted to an Int32 ID?  An Int32 from the database will fit in Int64.

Comment: the question for INT32 could be extended to INT64, int64 to int128 etc, etc, I asked about the mechanism to avoid to use bigger datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keeping all unsaved new objects with the default value of 0?
Or even better,  use an ORM like NHibernate or Entity framework to handle this?

Comment: As the objects are identified by IDs two objects with similar ids will be threated as similar objetcs, it's not good...

Comment: No if you implements Equals() in your POCOS and compare other relevant properties too.
See this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20592/Implementing-IEquatable-Properly

Comment: No other relevant properties available.

Answer (score 0):

Simply resetting back to -1 once you reach the lowest possible value will probably meet your needs:

```
Public Sub New()
    If _LastId > Interger.MinValue Then
        Me.Id = _LastId - 1
    Else
        Me.Id = -1
    End if
    ' ...
```

Comment: Well, I assumed based on your question that by the time you reached the minimum value, the highest temp value would already be freed up for re-use.  When do they get freed up for reuse?  Are they freed up in sequential order, or to they leave gaps in the available numbers?  I don't suppose changing the ID to a GUID is a possibility?  That would clearly be the best solution in this sort of design.

Comment: Wow, if Dog is only 100 bytes that is 200 GB of Dogs in memory if -1 is still around.

Comment: @serhio if you want a negative Integer as ID and have more than 2 billion items how could you possibly expect to have unique values?

Comment: no need to have more that 2 billion items. Is sufficient to have one item and destroy it 2 billion times...

Comment: @Steven: maybe my fist created dog survives, and other dogs are died and reborn billion of times...